# Overloading generic functions in Haskell

Tags: generics, haskell, overloading

I've come across a problem where I think I may have a gap in my knowledge of Haskell. I'm trying to implement a function called `after`, that will either be given an item or a list, and display what comes after it.

`after "sample" 'a'` should return "mple".

`after "sample" "am"` should return "ple".

I know how to define both of these functions as `after` and `afterList`, but I am trying to make a generic function to handle both

`after :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a`

and

`after :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]`

Is such a function possible? My attempt at this was:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
sub :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Int -> [a]
sub [] _ = []
sub _ 0 = []
sub (x:xs) c = sub xs (c - 1)

pos :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Int
pos [] _ = 0
pos (x:xs) c
  | x == c = 0
  | otherwise = 1 + pos xs c

class (Eq a) => Continuous [a] a where
  after x c = sub x (pos x c)

instance (Eq a) => Continuous [a] [a] where
  after [] _ = []
  after x c
    | take (length c) x == c = sub x ((length c)+1)
    | otherwise = after (tail x) c
```

But that returns an error of

```
test.hs:13:28:
  Unexpected type `[a]' where type variable expected
  In the declaration of `Continuous [a] a'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So, is my approach fundamentally flawed? How can one achieve generic function overloading, with or without typeclasses?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, and I'm very interested in solutions to this. Just a thought: I imagine you could just write afterList, and make sure to convert all individual items to singleton lists at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is quite right, but you need to write it out properly.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}

class Continuous list part where
  after :: list -> part -> list

instance (Eq a) => Continuous [a] a where
  after x c = sub x (pos x c)

instance (Eq a) => Continuous [a] [a] where
  after [] _ = []
  after x c
    | take (length c) x == c = sub x ((length c)+1)
    | otherwise = after (tail x) c
```

Note that your implementations don't seem to work, though. But they do type-check now.

Comment: This works. To make the above code work I changed the line in sub from `sub _ 0 = []` to `sub x 0 = x`. Didn't realize that classes used such generic terms in their definition.